# Retrieve currency exchange data from URL pages

Tags: delphi

At the end of the year, I have to execute a small project for a Delphi course at my university. I am trying to make a currency converter with real data. How can I take from a URL (ex: https://www.bnm.md/en/) official exchange rates for each currency and send them to a TLabel or TPanel or TEdit (I think it will be a string) so that I can manipulate the extracted data? Is it possible to implement this with JS? Or, are there other ways in Pascal to retrieve certain data from URL pages?

[image]

Comment: Probably the wrong way to do it. The right way would be to use a web service

Comment: Thanks David for the answer if you could help me understand what this is about, I would be grateful

Comment: I'd do some web search on the topic of web services

Comment: Thanks, I will try to found.

Comment: here is exchange rates as xml from bnm.md for today https://www.bnm.md/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=28.04.2020

Comment: Thanks sddk, very suggestive and helpful ... ;) sorry for the sarcasm.

Comment: You can use a HTTP component (ICS, Indy or other) to download the XML file. Then you can parse it using Delphi XML document parser. Parsing is the process of analysing the document and extract data.

Comment: fpiette, thanks a lot.